# How do I get the reference type corresponding to a primitive type?

Tags: java

I'd like a function mapping classes to classes, such that int.class -> Integer.

Comment: Can you give us a purpose for this?

Comment: Sure - I'm using reflection to fix up a broken Java API which I call from Jython.  The API uses Java integral types as if they were unsigned, e.g. shorts for the range 0 - 65535.  To that end, I need to find, say, Short.MAX_VALUE given short, and so on for all the integral types.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. The question seems unambiguous, and the answers appear to be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't specifically provided in the vanilla JDK, but if you don't want to whip up your own, [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) provides [`Primitives.wrap(Class)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Primitives.html#wrap%28java.lang.Class%29) that takes primitive types and returns the corresponding wrapper type.

Comment: Also [ClassUtils.primitiveToWrapper(Class)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ClassUtils.html#primitiveToWrapper(java.lang.Class)) does the same in Apache Commons Lang

Answer (score 1):

For integer:

```
int.class or the equivalent: Integer.TYPE;
```

Same for other primitive types

```
double.class or Double.TYPE
float.class or Float.TYPE
char.class or Character.TYPE
long.class or Long.TYPE
boolean.class Boolean.TYPE
```

Use it as follows:

```
Class intClass = int.class;
```

This then is a class that represents the primitive type int.

With that info, you simply write your own mapper: (You dont want to include an external lib for 8 lines of code)

```
public Class getClassForPrimitiveType(Class clazz) {
  if (clazz == int.class) return Integer.class;
  if (clazz == float.class) return Float.class;
  // TODO other primitives
}
```

Comment: This will give the class for the primitive type, i.e. `int.class` not `Integer.class`

Comment: Instead of `Integer.Type`, you can also use `int.class`; to me that's clearer and reduces the chance of mixing it up.

Comment: Updated: Thanks, i did not know int.class